# PHP cms installing

Tags: php, file, content-management-system, installation

I'm working on a cms and now I'm building the installation for it. My question is how should I save the mysql username, password etc after the user has entered them.
In the cms they are kept in the init.php and I'd like to store them to a temporary file for the installation, and then put the details to the init.php.
I tried to save them to a new file (db.php) but I got a PDO error which was odd.
How should this be done?

Basically I want to save this to a php file

```
$user = 'something';
```

But how to do it?

```
$file = fopen("db.php","w");
chmod("db.php", 0777); //the file is going to be deleted, so
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Please show us what exactly you have tried and what the error was you received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this block:

```
$filename='settings.php';
$fw=fopen("../".$filename,'w',true);
fwrite( $fw, "<?php 
            \$user = $user;
            include('engine.php');
        ?>");
fclose($fw);
```

Comment: How would you then paste the variables from the settings.php to the final init.php file? The file already exists, but not used so far so would it be best to create the file from scratch with php?

Comment: You should include it from your 'index.php'